# What is a 17th-century affectionate term for "Mother"?

Tags: single-word-requests, archaicisms, seventeenth-century-english

I'm writing a ghost story, and (in an admittedly well-worn trope) a child ghost is looking for its mother; however, how would a 17th-century child affectionately refer to its mother? In short, what would the 17th-century version of "Mummy" be?

The child would be British; middle-class (or its equivalent then); moderately educated; and home-schooled, the Bible being the main text book.

Comment: The age of the child seems relevant too. (If you were setting it in modern times, a five-year old ghost might refer to their mother as "mummy", a ten-yeur-old as "mum", and a 15-year-old perhaps might use "*uuuurrrgh…* **you**".) Also, regional dialects vary. (For example, "mam" is common in northern England, but not so much in the south.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Mama**

British English \mə-ˈmä\
(American English \ˈmä-mə\ or \məˈmɑ)

> Origin:  1545–55;
>     [mama](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mama) (also, mamma) nursery word, with parallels in other European
>   languages, probably in part inherited or borrowed, in part newly
>   formed; compare Latin *mamma*, Greek *mámmē*  breast, *mama*,
>   French *maman*, Welsh *mam*  mother

[Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mamma&allowed_in_frame=0) says ***mamma***, (spelled with a double -m), is dated in 1570s

> representing the native form of the reduplication of *ma- that is
>   nearly universal among the Indo-European languages [...] Its late appearance in English is curious, but Middle English had ***mome*** (mid-13c.) "an aunt; an old woman," also an affectionate term of address for an older woman. **In educated usage, the stress is always on the last syllable**. In terms of recorded usage of related words in English, *mama* is from 1707, *mum* is from 1823, *mummy* in this sense from 1839, *mommy* 1844, *momma* 1852, and *mom* 1867.

Comment: Thanks - would up-vote, but I'm new here so can't yet!

Comment: +1 OED tells us that *mamma* is preceded by *Mam* (often alongside *Dad*, both possibly of Welsh origin); that it is not widely attested until the late 17th C; that it is probably derived from French *maman*, which would account for the final stress; and that that final stress is characteristic of upper-class (or wannabe upper-class) usage, while the less exalted employ first-syllable stress, as do Americans.

Comment: Linguists tell us that because "mama" is among the first sounds that a baby makes while innocently babbling along and trying these interesting sound things, it is very widespread among many languages.